# RedisJSON add TTL on specific Value in JSON Object

Tags: node.js, json, redis, redisjson

Hey working with redisJSON
NodeJS
package npm Redis 4.3.1

Key (userID):(Country) with values Json

Example

data = {
"info": {
"name":"test",
"email": "test@test,test"
},
"suppliers": {
"s1": 1,
"s2": 22
},
"suppliersCap": {
"s1": 0,
"s2": 10
}
}

redis.json.set('22:AU', '.', data);

now I try to add TTL for 5 minutes on the specific key in the JSON
for example on this key

22:AU .data.suppliersCap.s2, after 5 minutes the cap will be 0;

bit this not works

redis.json.set(`22:AU`, '.data.suppliersCap.s2', {
EX: 300
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NX` and `XX` are the only valid [modifiers](https://redis.io/commands/json.set/) for the command:

```js
redisClient.json.set(
  key: string, 
  path: string, 
  json: RedisJSON, 
  options?: NX | XX | undefined
): Promise<"OK" | null>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set TTL on an inner element of a RedisJSON object.

Note: It can be done only on an entire RedisJSON object.